# How to read csv correctly in angular/typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my `angular` application i am reading the `csv`. My function looks like this

```js
  onUploadFileChanges(files: File[]) {
    if (!lodash.isEmpty(files)) {
      const uploadedFile:Blob = lodash.last(files) as Blob;
      if (!uploadedFile) {
        throw new Error('uploaded file not fuond');
      }
      const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(uploadedFile);
      reader.onload = () => {
        const csv = reader.result as string;
        const rowStrings = csv.split(/\r|\n|\r/);
        let headers = rowStrings.shift()?.split(CSV_DELIMITER);
        let rows: Array<Array<string>> = [];
        rowStrings.forEach((row: any) => {
          rows.push(row.split(CSV_DELIMITER));
        });
        headers = headers?.map((header) => {
          header = header.trim();
          return header;
        });
        console.log('rows : ', rows);
        console.log('headers : ', headers);
        if (headers && headers.length) {
          rows = lodash.filter(rows, (row) => row.length > (headers ? headers.length : 0) / 2); // remove rows with half or more cells empty
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

I have a custom file type which extends `Blob` which is like this

```js
export interface File extends Blob {
    id?: string;
    name: string;
    lastModified: number;
    progress?: number;
    uploadPromise?: Subscription;
    isUploadFailed?: boolean;
    size: number;
    publicUrl?: string;
    publicUrlExpiredAt?: string;
    type: string;
}
```

but that custom file type imported like this

```
import { File as CustomFile } from '@myLibrary/cs-tools';
```

But inside of my function i am using Native `File` type and casting it to `Blob`

But when i am browsing the file so it is throwing this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-csv-parser). You don't want to deal with escaping and special characters etc.

Comment: Did you understand that why error is coming?

Comment: That is another question unrelated to your title. Please write accurate title.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything related/specific to Angular.

Comment: Your question is about reading a file, not parsing csv.

Comment: Is the `File` type in your ts file the native [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) type? Would you happen to imported a module with a type named `File` so it has overwritten the native `File` type?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev i mentioned that i am trying to parse csv in my angular project and in that i am using typescript. So both are linked togather.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev i have updated the title of question

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you interface on top of this

```
guessCSVDelimiter(csv: string, delimiters: string[] = [';',',','\t'], fallbackDelimiter: string = '\t'): string {
  const validDelimiters = delimiters.filter(checkDelimiter);
  return validDelimiters.length > 0 ? validDelimiters[0] : fallbackDelimiter;

  function checkDelimiter(delimiter) {
    let cache = -1;
    return csv.split('\n').every(checkLength);
    function checkLength(line) {
      if (!line) return true;
      const length = line.split(delimiter).length;
      if (cache < 0) cache = length;
      return cache === length && length > 1;
    }
  }
}


csvToJson(csv: string) {
  let array =  [];
  let header: any = [];

      // return empty array if there is no data
    if (!csv) return [];

    // replace comma with a dot to interpret float and double values
    csv = csv.replace(/"/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');

    // check string separator
    const delimiter = guessCSVDelimiter(csv);

    // split text by lines
    const lines = csv.split("\r");

    // removes the first item from array of lines which contains names of columns and saves it in variable header
    header = lines.shift().split(delimiter);

    lines.forEach(line => {
      if (line === "\n") return;
      let splitLine = line.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(delimiter);
      let lineObject = {};

      for(let i=0; i<splitLine.length; i++) {
        // if(Number(splitLine[i])) splitLine[i] = Number(splitLine[i]); <<<<<<< number parser
        lineObject[header[i]] = splitLine[i];
      }
      array.push(lineObject)
    })
    return array;
}
```